# Javascript ExcelJS how to force a column to format as text

Tags: javascript, excel, asp.net-core, exceljs

I'm creating and downloading a .csv to be used as a template for uploading batch data for processing.  One of the columns (correlating to a string in the class) will be used to enter a five-character string that the user can copy and paste from a list of entries.

My problem arises with some of the entries having a leading zero. When you enter 01532, for example, it is treated as numeric and the leading zero is dropped. Obviously you can start your entry with a quote mark and it will force it to be treated as alpha and retain the leading zero, but I'd prefer to handle that for my users.

I'm defining numFmt as '@@' (escaped @ sign since it's in a razor page), and it doesn't throw an error, but it also doesn't fix the problem.

```
               customizeCell: function (options) {
                    var gridCell = options.gridCell;
                    var excelCell = options.excelCell;

                    if (gridCell.rowType === "data") {
                        if (gridCell.column.dataField === 'AlphaCode') {
                            excelCell.numFmt = '@@';
                        }
                    }
                }
```